# Java torrent client: tTorrent doesn't resume download

Tags: java, bittorrent, torrent

I tried to use the `ttorrent Java library` to develop a simple Java `BitTorrent client` but, although the download starts and works fine the first time, when I stop and than I try to resume it doesn't work.

Here's the code (there are 3 classes):

First class:

```
package rar.torrent;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;

import com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client;
import com.turn.ttorrent.client.SharedTorrent;

public class TorrentFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final String APRI_BTN = "APRI_BTN";
    private static final String SCEGLI_BTN = "SCEGLI_BTN";
    private static final String PLAY_STOP_BTN = "PLAY_STOP_BTN";

    private static final String PLAY_TXT = "Play";
    private static final String STOP_TXT = "Stop";

    private JTextField torrentFileText = null;
    private JTextField destinazioneText = null;

    private JButton apriButton = null;
    private JButton scegliButton = null;
    private JButton playStopButton = null;

    private JProgressBar jpb = null;

    private JLabel peerLabel = null;

    private JFileChooser torrentJFC = null;
    private JFileChooser directoryJFC = null;

    private SharedTorrent torrent = null;
    private Client client = null;

    private DownloadThread dt = null;

    private File torrentFile = null;
    private File destinazioneFile = null;

    private Thread t = null;

    public TorrentFrame (){
        super("RARTorrent");
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,1));

        JPanel filePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,3));
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Seleziona file torrent:");
        torrentFileText = new JTextField(20);
        torrentFileText.setText("");
        torrentFileText.setEditable(false);
        apriButton = new JButton("Apri");
        apriButton.setActionCommand(APRI_BTN);
        apriButton.addActionListener(this);
        filePanel.add(label);
        filePanel.add(torrentFileText);
        filePanel.add(apriButton);

        JPanel fileDestPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,3));
        JLabel labelDest = new JLabel("Seleziona destinazioneText:");
        destinazioneText = new JTextField(20);
        destinazioneText.setText("");
        destinazioneText.setEditable(false);
        scegliButton = new JButton("Scegli");
        scegliButton.setActionCommand(SCEGLI_BTN);
        scegliButton.addActionListener(this);
        fileDestPanel.add(labelDest);
        fileDestPanel.add(destinazioneText);
        fileDestPanel.add(scegliButton);

        playStopButton = new JButton(PLAY_TXT);
        playStopButton.setActionCommand(PLAY_STOP_BTN);
        playStopButton.addActionListener(this);

        jpb = new JProgressBar(0,100);
        jpb.setStringPainted(true);

        peerLabel = new JLabel("Download non in corso");

        torrentJFC = new JFileChooser();
        torrentJFC.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        torrentJFC.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        torrentJFC.setFileFilter(new TorrentFileFilter());

        directoryJFC = new JFileChooser();
        directoryJFC.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

        mainPanel.add(filePanel);
        mainPanel.add(fileDestPanel);
        mainPanel.add(playStopButton);
        mainPanel.add(jpb); 
        mainPanel.add(peerLabel);

        this.add(mainPanel);

        this.pack();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class TorrentFileFilter extends FileFilter{

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File f) {
            String ext = null;
            String s = f.getName();
            int i = s.lastIndexOf('.');

            if (i > 0 &&  i < s.length() - 1) {
                ext = s.substring(i+1).toLowerCase();
            }

            if (ext != null && ext.equals("torrent"))
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "Torrent files";
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        String ev = arg0.getActionCommand();

        if(ev.equalsIgnoreCase(APRI_BTN)){          
            int returnVal = torrentJFC.showOpenDialog(this);

            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                torrentFile = torrentJFC.getSelectedFile();
                torrentFileText.setText(torrentFile.getName());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Chiuso 'Apri file'");
            }           
        }

        if(ev.equalsIgnoreCase(PLAY_STOP_BTN)){
            if (playStopButton.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(STOP_TXT)){
                client.stop();
                dt.stop();
                client = null;
                t = null;
                dt = null;
                torrent = null;
                playStopButton.setText(PLAY_TXT);
                return;
            }

            if (playStopButton.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(PLAY_TXT) && !torrentFileText.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !destinazioneText.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                try {
                    torrent = SharedTorrent.fromFile(torrentFile, destinazioneFile);
                    client = new Client(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),torrent);
                    client.setMaxDownloadRate(1000.0);
                    client.setMaxUploadRate(50.0);
                    client.download();

                    jpb.setValue(0);
                    peerLabel.setText("Non in download");
                    dt = new DownloadThread(jpb,peerLabel,torrent);
                    t = new Thread (dt);
                    t.start();

                    playStopButton.setText(STOP_TXT);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
                }
            }           
        }

        if(ev.equalsIgnoreCase(SCEGLI_BTN)){
            int returnVal = directoryJFC.showSaveDialog(this);

            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                destinazioneFile = directoryJFC.getSelectedFile();
                destinazioneText.setText(destinazioneFile.getName());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Chiuso 'Scegli'");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Second class:

```
package rar.torrent;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

import com.turn.ttorrent.client.SharedTorrent;

public class DownloadThread implements Runnable {
    private JProgressBar jpb = null;
    private SharedTorrent torrent = null;
    private JLabel peerLabel = null;

    private int completedPieces = 0;
    private int pieceCount = 0;
    private int availablePieces = 0;
    private int requestedPieces = 0;

    private String peerLabelText = "";

    private boolean stop = false;

    public DownloadThread(JProgressBar jpb, JLabel peerLabel, SharedTorrent torrent){
        super();
        this.jpb = jpb;
        this.torrent = torrent;
        this.peerLabel = peerLabel;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!torrent.isComplete() && !stop){
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

            float perc = torrent.getCompletion();
            int percInt = (int) perc;
            int jpbValue = jpb.getValue();
            if (percInt > jpbValue)
                jpb.setValue(percInt);

            //TODO Sistemare il bug della "," nella stringa sostituendola con il "."
            String stringToFloat = jpb.getString().substring(0, jpb.getString().length() -1);
            int comaChar = stringToFloat.lastIndexOf(",");
            char [] transformString = stringToFloat.toCharArray();
            if (comaChar > 0)
                transformString [comaChar] = '.';
            stringToFloat = new String(transformString);

            if (perc > Float.parseFloat(stringToFloat))
                jpb.setString(String.format("%.2f", perc) + "%");

            completedPieces = torrent.getCompletedPieces().cardinality();
            pieceCount = torrent.getPieceCount();
            availablePieces = torrent.getAvailablePieces().cardinality();
            requestedPieces = torrent.getRequestedPieces().cardinality();

            if (isPeerLabelTextModified(cal,sdf)){
                peerLabelText = completedPieces + "/" + pieceCount + " pieces [" + availablePieces + "/" + requestedPieces + "] \n" + sdf.format(cal.getTime());
                peerLabel.setText(peerLabelText);
            }

        }
    }

    private boolean isPeerLabelTextModified (Calendar cal, SimpleDateFormat sdf){
        String test = completedPieces + "/" + pieceCount + " pieces [" + availablePieces + "/" + requestedPieces + "]  " + sdf.format(cal.getTime());
        return !peerLabelText.equalsIgnoreCase(test);
    }

    public void stop(){
        this.stop = true;
    }
}
```

Third class:

```
package rar.torrent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class RARTorrent{    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TorrentFrame();
            }});
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you get any errors? Have you tried debugging or adding logging to the resume functionality?

Comment: I tried both, debugging and logging. I think that my code works fine but I'm not sure about this: am I using in the wrong way the library or are there any bugs in the library?

Comment: Obviously, I always use the same torrent file and the same destination folder, in fact the software finds the downloading files, gives me the infos about the downloaded pieces, but doesn't continue the download.

Comment: Is there nobody who can help me?

Comment: You could try putting the logging level to DEBUG and see what the lib is doing